# Как можно сделать так, чтобы при увеличинии текста блок увеличивался в ширину?

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при увеличении текста блок увеличивался в ширину, и если места не хватает, то он смещается вниз?

Как можно это сделать при помощи `grid`? сетка `3/3` может быть `8` или `9` элементов.

Пример изображения:

[image: Пример изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Расположить блоки с текстом друг за другом с помощью `display:inline-block`, маргинов нужного размера и запрета на перенос слов внутри не вариант?

Comment: Я думал, inline block уже не используют.

Comment: вы где-то видели статус deprecated у этого свойства?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде то что вы хотели?
"min-width: calc(33% - 18px);" - это дефолтная ширина на три блока в ряду
А "width: max-content;" - отвечает за ширину текстов длиннее "min-width" которые.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style: none;
  width: max-content;
  min-width: calc(33% - 18px);
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Длинный Длинный Длинный текст 1</li>
  <li>Длинный текст 2</li>
  <li>Длинный текст 3</li>
  <li>Длинный текст 4</li>
  <li>Длинный текст 5</li>
  <li>Длинный текст 6</li>
  <li>Длинный Длинный Длинный Длинный Длинный текст 7</li>
  <li>Длинный текст 8</li>
  <li>Длинный текст 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: если текст длинный, элементов в строке должно стать два вместо трех.

Comment: @Инквизитор сделал изменения по вашей просьбе

Answer (score 0):

Инлайн-блок:

```css
span {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}

div {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Длинный Длинный Длинный текст 1</span>
  <span>текст 2</span>
  <span>Длинный текст 3</span>
  <span>Длинный теееееекст 4</span>
  <span>Длинный текккст 5</span>
  <span>Длинный текст 6</span>
  <span>Длинный тееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееееекст 7</span>
  <span>Длинный теккккст 8</span>
  <span>текст 9</span>
</div>
```